# Reverse the strings in the column relative to the characters in the middle of the string

Tags: python

I have a column of phone numbers. How can I flip them with regards to the two digits in the middle.

```
# The original column
[["00-07-16"],
 ["23-27-21"],
 ["01-12-16"]]
```

```
# The reversed column
[["16-07-00"],
 ["21-27-23"],
 ["16-12-01"]]
```

Comment: Can you write code that gets the correct result for one of the numbers? Do you know how to apply that function to each element of the original list? (If not, where exactly are you stuck?) If you put those two things together, can you solve the problem?

Comment: If the "phone numbers" are guaranteed to be of the form NN-NN-NN then some judicious slicing is probably the easiest way to do this. Try it. You'll like it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this function to reverse each number :

```
def rev(num:str):
    return num[6:8] + num[2:6] + num[0:2]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
reversed_list = []

for el in original_list:
    splitted = el[0].split('-')
    new_el = splitted[2] + '-' + splitted[1] + '-' + splitted[0]
    reversed_list.append([new_el])
```

Your column look like dates. You should try to use [strptime and strftime](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime)

Answer (score 0):

A regex-approach.

```
import re

lst = [["00-07-16"], ["23-27-21"], ["01-12-16"]]

pattern = re.compile(r'^(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})$')
out = []
for text in lst:
    out.append(pattern.sub(r'\3-\2-\1', text[0]))

print(out)
```

- In case the digits on the left or in right are more than 2 (don't know what kind of phone numbers are they) you could modify the as `r'(\d+)-(\d{2})-(\d+)'`
- in case you know the exact amount of digits, i.e. N and M, `r'(\d{N})-(\d{2})-(\d{M})'`

Just for fun: by composition of functions

```
from operator import itemgetter, methodcaller

lst = [["00-07-16"], ["23-27-21"], ["01-12-16"]]

map('-'.join, map(itemgetter(2, 1, 0), map(methodcaller('split', '-'), map(itemgetter(0), lst))))
```